# ¿Es correcta esta relacion circular de base de datos?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Tengo actualmente el siguiente modelo de base de datos:

[image]

1. La tabla **devices** tiene una relacion de un a muchos en **network_cards**
2. La tabla **network_cards** tiene una relacion de uno a uno en la tabla
   **switches**
   Mi duda es en la tabla de suppliers uno a uno con la tabla **switches** y **devices**,

¿Es correcto mi modelo? ¿Que podria mejorar o eliminar?

Espero me puedan orientar aun no tengo bien claro el concepto de relaciones circulares
Gracias

Comment: si bien se "ve raro" en un principio, no es realmente una relación circular como tal. Lo importante sería saber si un "id_device" que esté con un "id_switch" pueden tener diferentes suppliers

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué es un switch y qué es un device? ¿Por qué son diferentes teniendo los mismos atributos?

Será que una normalización de esto termina en que hay un campo `device_type` (guardado en otra tabla o representado como un id en la tabla device) y en esa nueva tabla `device` estarían todos los *devices*, incluidos los switches?

```
|supplier|----|device|----<|network_cards|
```

Lo otro: las entidades tienen nombre en singular. **Device, Switch, Network_card, supplier**; cada registro representa *un device, un switch, un networkcard, un supplier*